# SQL Multi Conditional CASE WHEN issues

Tags: sql, database, case-when

I am encountering a problem when trying to use a CASE WHEN for the following scenario:

I have a table with more than 3 columns but these 3 are the only relevant ones: order_number, payment_method, order_date.

There can be multiple "orders" per order_number. There will never be two of the same order_date

| Order Number | Payment Method | Order Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 120 | Cash | 01/01/2021 |
| 175 | Credit Card | 01/02/2021 |
| 209 | Cash | 01/03/2021 |
| 209 | Credit Card | 01/04/2021 |
| 209 | Personal Check | 01/05/2021 |
| 209 | Credit Card | 01/06/2021 |
| 209 | Cash | 01/07/2021 |
| 209 | Personal Check | 01/08/2021 |
| 277 | Credit Card | 01/09/2021 |
| 301 | Cash | 01/10/2021 |
| 333 | Personal Check | 01/11/2021 |
| 333 | Cash | 01/12/2021 |
| 333 | Cash | 01/13/2021 |
| 333 | Personal Check | 01/14/2021 |
| 400 | Credit Card | 01/15/2021 |
| 551 | Credit Card | 01/16/2021 |
| 551 | Cash | 01/17/2021 |
| 680 | Personal Check | 01/18/2021 |

I am trying to consolidate it so that I have a list with only 1 row per order number, based on the following logic:

1. If there is only 1 order number  - return the order date
2. If there are >1 alike order numbers and  any of those orders was paid with a credit card - return the most recent order date that was paid by credit card
3. If there are >1 alike order numbers and none of the orders were paid with a credit card  - return the most recent order date.

And the goal would look like this:

| Order Number | Payment Method | Order Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 120 | Cash | 01/01/2021 |
| 175 | Credit Card | 01/02/2021 |
| 209 | Credit Card | 01/06/2021 |
| 277 | Credit Card | 01/09/2021 |
| 301 | Cash | 01/10/2021 |
| 333 | Personal Check | 01/14/2021 |
| 400 | Credit Card | 01/15/2021 |
| 551 | Credit Card | 01/16/2021 |
| 680 | Personal Check | 01/18/2021 |

No duplicate order numbers, and when there were duplicate order numbers, the logic was followed and that row was pulled.

I tried various methods of CASE WHEN, but always fail when it comes to applying a condition on the THEN part.

Comment: avoid posting images. it is hard for us to work with. post your code and anything relevant as text if possible

Comment: Please edit your question to contain sample data and expected results, ideally as `insert` statement but at least as text, [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Sorry about that! I've updated to be text tables instead of images.

Comment: Please add a tag with the DBMS you're using as the syntax for the proposed solution may vary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general method, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select o.*
from (select o.*,
             row_number() over (partition by order_number
                                order by (case when payment_method = 'Credit Card' then 1 else 2 end),
                                         order_date desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from orders o
     ) o
where seqnum = 1;
```

This is generic SQL and should work in any database.  However, depending on your database there might be shortcuts.

Comment: Wow, thank you !!! That is awesome, it worked. You're a life saver.

Comment: If I had to take the logic a step more complicated, could this be accomplished by adjusting the CASE WHEN in your code?.....if orders = 1, then use timestamp from order....................
if orders = 2 and one is a credit card, use date from oldest credit card order..........
if orders = 2 and none are credit card, use MOST RECENT order date..........
if orders > 2 and one is a credit card, use date from oldest credit card order.......
if orders > 2 and none are credit card, use OLDEST order date..........

Comment: @none_of_my_bikes_run . . . It is better to ask a new question, with a clear explanation and sample data and desired results.

Comment: Will do, thanks for the help. New here learning the etiquette .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66920229/sql-multi-conditional-case-when-issues-part-2-logic-adjustments

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would work:

```
SELECT o.order_number, MAX(COALESCE(tc.latest_cc_tran, o.order_date)) AS latest_date
FROM order o
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT MAX(ot.tran_date) latest_cc_tran
    FROM order_tran ot
    WHERE ot.order_number = o.order_number
) tc
GROUP BY o.order_number
```

Note: I did not test the query, but it should convey the gist.