# SQL Multi Conditional CASE WHEN issues [Part 2 - logic adjustments]

Tags: sql, database, case-when

I have a follow up question to a question I posted yesterday. Today there are changes to the logic needed.
[SQL Multi Conditional CASE WHEN issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66911641/sql-multi-conditional-case-when-issues/66912424?noredirect=1#comment118290955_66912424)

Example data table is at the bottom of this post. The original code was written around the following logic:

1. If there is only 1 order number - return the order date
2. If there are >1 alike order numbers and any of those orders was paid with a credit card - return the most recent order date that was paid by credit card
3. If there are >1 alike order numbers and none of the orders were paid with a credit card - return the most recent order date.

Credit to user Gordon Linoff who provided the following code which worked perfectly:

```
    select o.*
from (select o.*,
             row_number() over (partition by order_number
                                order by (case when payment_method = 'Credit Card' then 1 else 2 end),
                                         order_date desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from orders o
     ) o
where seqnum = 1;
```

There have been updates to the requirements in the logic which have been expanded to the following:

1. if orders = 1, then use timestamp from order
2. if orders = 2 and one is a credit card, use date from oldest credit card order.
3. if orders = 2 and none are credit card, use the RECENT order date.
4. if orders > 2 and any are credit card, use date from oldest credit card order.
5. if orders > 2 and none are credit card, use the OLDEST order date.

Can this be accomplished by modifying the CASE WHEN in Gordon's code? Or does it require more than that simple of a change.

Original Data Table in question:

| Order Number | Payment Method | Order Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 120 | Cash | 01/01/2021 |
| 175 | Credit Card | 01/02/2021 |
| 209 | Cash | 01/03/2021 |
| 209 | Credit Card | 01/04/2021 |
| 209 | Personal Check | 01/05/2021 |
| 209 | Credit Card | 01/06/2021 |
| 209 | Cash | 01/07/2021 |
| 209 | Personal Check | 01/08/2021 |
| 277 | Credit Card | 01/09/2021 |
| 301 | Cash | 01/10/2021 |
| 333 | Personal Check | 01/11/2021 |
| 333 | Cash | 01/12/2021 |
| 333 | Cash | 01/13/2021 |
| 333 | Personal Check | 01/14/2021 |
| 400 | Credit Card | 01/15/2021 |
| 551 | Credit Card | 01/16/2021 |
| 551 | Cash | 01/17/2021 |
| 680 | Personal Check | 01/18/2021 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get this logic correctly, it is:

- Take the oldest order date, if any are on credit cards.
- Take the newest order date, if there are exactly two orders and there are no credit cards.
- Otherwise, take the oldest order date.

You can get the auxiliary information using another subquery and window functions:

```
select o.*
from (select o.*,
             row_number() over (partition by order_number
                                order by (case when cnt = 2 and num_cc = 0 then order_date end) desc,
                                         order_date asc
                               ) as seqnum
      from (select o.*,
                   count(*) over (partition by order_number) as cnt,
                   sum(case when payment_method = 'Credit Card' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by order_number) as num_cc
            from orders o
           ) o
     ) o
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Is there a THEN or a close to the first CASE WHEN up there? case when cnt_cc desc, is where it's fighting me

Comment: @none_of_my_bikes_run . . . No.  I thought I had deleted the entire expression, but missed part of it.

Comment: Man, this is so close. And its starting to make more sense to me. The only condition it's not meeting its when there are multiple CC orders, its pulling the oldest date regardless of payment method. I am currently trying to add another order by condition in that same area that specifies if any are on credit card to take the oldest credit card order, rather than simply the oldest order in general

Comment: I added
   (CASE WHEN cnt > 2 AND num_cc > 0 THEN payment_method END) ASC, 
because out of pure luck, in the un-obfuscated data here "credit card" value is actually the highest alphabetically. So this condition adds a layer when count is greater than 2 and there is any number of CC payments, it'll sort the sequence starting with CC records instead of records with other payment methods.. seems to be working..

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I checked out your book, I'm definitely picking up a copy!